# Is it possible to locate a cellphone's location just by ringing it?

Tags: mobile, phone

With today's technology, is it possible to locate a cellphone's location just by ringing it, kind of like what we see in movies?

Comment: No need to ring (a phone can be forced to re-acquire the cell). Rough location is inferred from the cell it's registered with, and exact location (about 2 meters' CEP) is obtained from trilateration (see TDOA technique).

Comment: Also, the answer is "yes" if the phone in question is within hearing range.

Comment: My phone is usually lost in the couch when I can't find it so ringing it usually does the trick unless the ringer is off ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phone does not need to be rung or even on in some cases.  (This is why in some secure facilities, the battery is removed from uncertified phones.)  Phones are constantly in communication with their local radio towers when on and some will even periodically poll when off.  It is also possible for commands to be remote issued to the radio's on the phones to gather additional information.

At a minimum, the radio towers that it communicates with are known as is the relative signal strength which gives a rough approximation.  In some cases, it may even be possible to get a GPS location depending on how things are implemented in the phone's radio.